# Retrieve username/password from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, passwords

My web server has authentication enabled. When I access my web server i get a pop-up from browser for username and password. After logged in, I want to retrieve the username from the browser using javascript.  I am not using any kind of form to get the username/password. So, I am not setting any cookies also. 
Can we use DOM method to access the username? or any other way?

Regards,
Anandan

Comment: Which web server? Are you using a server-side framework?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , you can't do that with javascript.

Check this link from php.net :

HTTP authentication with PHP :
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're talking about a apache directory authentication (basic/digest) ? If so you can't do that directly using javascript. You need to provide session information (username) retrived at the server side and passed to your browser. i.e (php script passing a Json object)

Comment: yes. I am using basic auth. I will try the method you suggested. But is there any reason 'why we can't do it from java script?'

Comment: You can't because javascript runs on the client side not on the server.